# How to configure Log4j in Spring for MyBatis SQL queries?

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, log4j, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have the a Spring MVC project with mybatis 3.3.0 and mybatis-spring 1.2.3 and I want to configure log4j in my project. And I'm not using `mybatis-config.xml` for setting up mybatis sql session factory. So I cannot use the following setting,

```
<configuration>
  <settings>
    ...
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
    ...
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

So, I have the following config in my

*spring-context.xml*,

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.sample.model"/>
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/sample/mappers/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.sample.mappers" />
</bean>
```

And configured this *log4j.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%p] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="java.sql" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> 
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.apache.ibatis" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.mybatis.spring" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.sample.mappers">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <root>
    <priority value ="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The above configuration doesn't print the sql queries executed or the prepared statements. So as documented in [mybatis logging](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) page and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110262/1793718), I used the log4j.properties instead of xml config,

*log4j.properties*

```
# Global logging configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# MyBatis logging configuration...
log4j.logger.com.sample.mappers=DEBUG

# SqlMap logging configuration.
log4j.logger.org.mybatis.spring=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner=DEBUG

log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG

# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] %c{1} - %m%n
```

I had the common-logging removed from the pom.xml too. But that also doesn't seem to work.

- How to set MyBatis to print all the sql queries(PreparedStatements)?
- If in case MyBatis is not detecting the log4j, Is there any way to tell MyBatis to use log4j as the default logging framework without using the `mybatis-config.xml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution and now I can see all the Prepared Statements and all of the Mapper interface queries & parameters in my console. Invoking this line of code once the server started up before calling any MyBatis queries works fine,

```
org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useLog4JLogging();
```

Other methods for other loggin frameworks are [mentioned here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html).

> If you choose to call one of these methods, you should do so before
>   calling any other MyBatis method. Also, these methods will only switch
>   to the requested log implementation if that implementation is
>   available on the runtime classpath. For example, if you try to select
>   Log4J logging and Log4J is not available at runtime, then MyBatis will
>   ignore the request to use Log4J and will use it's normal algorithm for
>   discovering logging implementations.

I also hided the following two dependencies in my pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I set to use log4j as default logger using `useLog4JLogging()` method, in console I could see MyBatis picking up the log4j as its logger framework now.

```
[DEBUG] org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory - Logging initialized using 'class org.apache.ibatis.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl' adapter.
```

Comment: Where should I invoke org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useLog4JLogging(); ? Keep in mind that I have no (neither one) xml file - all configured in annotaions

Comment: @HaskellFun Call it in any controller method before your mybatis executes. I had it in my controller method which shows home page screen which is prior to calling a mybatis queries. Identify the first mybatis query called in your application and call the method before that. Works for me in a fully annotation configured application too.

Comment: Yes, it works. But it is not a good idea, I think it should be configured somewhere else in XML or property file.