# Show SQL trace (Springboot+Mybatis)

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

My project is built with Spring boot and Mybatis, I want to see the sql query statements, what can I do?

Comment: There are some options given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27060563/217324)

Comment: Another option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635058/ibatis-get-executed-sql

Comment: Here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082834/ibatis-spring-how-to-log-the-sql-that-is-executed/4110262#4110262

Comment: Note: ibatis is the old name of Mybatis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-boot with spring-mybatis - how to force it to logging all SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001188/spring-boot-with-spring-mybatis-how-to-force-it-to-logging-all-sql-queries)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your mappers are in a package `your.pkg.mapper`, adding the following line to `application.properties` tells MyBatis to print statements, parameters and query results.

```
logging.level.your.pkg.mapper=TRACE
```

The below is the console output of the [sample project](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml).

```
2019-05-17 01:01:01.631 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.CityMapper.selectCityById     : ==>  Preparing: select id, name, state, country from city where id = ? 
2019-05-17 01:01:01.671 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.CityMapper.selectCityById     : ==> Parameters: 1(Long)
2019-05-17 01:01:01.705 TRACE 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.CityMapper.selectCityById     : <==    Columns: ID, NAME, STATE, COUNTRY
2019-05-17 01:01:01.705 TRACE 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.CityMapper.selectCityById     : <==        Row: 1, San Francisco, CA, US
2019-05-17 01:01:01.711 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.CityMapper.selectCityById     : <==      Total: 1
2019-05-17 01:01:01.724 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.HotelMapper.selectByCityId    : ==>  Preparing: select city, name, address, zip from hotel where city = ? 
2019-05-17 01:01:01.724 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.HotelMapper.selectByCityId    : ==> Parameters: 1(Integer)
2019-05-17 01:01:01.724 TRACE 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.HotelMapper.selectByCityId    : <==    Columns: CITY, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP
2019-05-17 01:01:01.724 TRACE 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.HotelMapper.selectByCityId    : <==        Row: 1, Conrad Treasury Place, William & George Streets, 4001
2019-05-17 01:01:01.725 DEBUG 76540 --- [           main] s.m.mapper.HotelMapper.selectByCityId    : <==      Total: 1
```

If you don't need query results, change the log level to `DEBUG`.

It also is possible to set different log level per mapper/statement.
Please see the [doc](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) for details.